# Is there a Cache Scheduler?

Tags: linux, cache, scheduling

I am trying to understand how Schedulers work in Linux. I am aware that there is an I/O scheduler and CPU scheduler in Linux. My question is how does Last Level Cache scheduling work? Is there any scheduler for it? I know the basic concepts of memory hierarchy but I am unable to connect them all together. Any guidance or sources to relevant information will be highly appreciated.